# Restore Eclipse Toolbar in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am sorry in advance for the stupid question but I am not a Mac user. For some reason the toolbar (which contains icons like run, debug ....) are gone. Usually there is a button on the top upper right of the window to restore it but for Eclipse it is not there. Can anyone help?
[image: Screenshot of Eclipse]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was hidden by right-clicking toolbar and selecting "Hide Toolbar".  Go to Window > Show Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac it is

```
Window -> Show Toolbar.
```

[image]